# Using Scripting API Library in Dymola

Tags: libraries, dymola, openmodelica

I would like to execute a *python* function with a C wrapper in Dymola, like shown in this [tutorial](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/interop_c_python.html#calling-external-python-code-from-a-modelica-model).
However, I can not execute the commands `stringReplace(readFile("pycflags"),"\n","");`, because I get the error message `Undeclared function stringReplace` and resp. `Undeclared function readFile`.
These functions are part of the **Scripting API** of the Open Modelica Library from [here](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html).

Can I use the Scripting API in Dymola? If yes, how can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the OpenModelica scripting API in Dymola. `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.readFile` is similar to OpenModelica `readFile`, but it returns an array of strings instead of a single string (and `sum(stringArray)` is not valid Modelica so you would need to write your own function to create a single string from the array, which likely will not run very fast).
`Modelica.Utilities.Strings.replace` is a direct replacement for `stringReplace`.

You would need to have the Modelica Standard Library open to use the functions above (which is slow particularly on Windows, so OpenModelica has its scripting API with some functions similar to the MSL).